# Rooms database save and retrieve object using converter

Tags: java, android, type-conversion, android-room, room

when i was trying to save an object using rooms database, data insertion was successful. while retrieving data, a value inside the object, which was an object, was retrieved as array. Converting the array back to object is not working. Other string, and integer values inside the root object was retrieved properly.

Saved object :

> [[F@6c173ab

Retrieved object:

> [[0.0066505815,
> 0.00605235, 0.0044598486, -0.011793762, 0.0069282507, -0.059397057, -0.058320906, 0.17123938, -0.019021105, -0.1037456, 0.0018062548, -0.005069571, 0.0035884415, 0.0017127255, 0.004238736, -0.058450952, -0.007079399, -0.010851874, 9.1687456E-4, 0.013117686, 0.26496187, -0.056337364, 0.054294083, 0.0023271786, 0.19248551, -0.031670928, 0.004658082, -0.042408537, -0.08871324, -0.13611381, 0.0048175915, 0.060110737, -0.05661096, -0.004599247, 0.02567487, -0.14492176, 0.41225138, 0.037969578, -0.0060184584, 0.16407079, -0.007605861, -0.004265492, -0.0011223844, 0.006605887, -0.008077469, 0.0015253898, -0.10189122, 0.050602783, 0.0058309403, 0.057144053, 0.07865115, -0.0022470118, 0.005851626, -0.001395651, -0.061264377, -0.007627005, -0.1531251, -8.3948084E-4, 0.02980912, -0.002113619, -0.0018161217, -0.10022795, 0.12291724, 0.07126657, 1.6772193E-4, 0.022098381, 0.0026675903, 0.03227209, 0.011782837, 0.006000733, 0.009471676, 0.036371186, -0.23033214, -0.002258695, 0.039965842, -0.00845738, 0.0025282402, 6.5926113E-4, 0.03005817, 0.032968543, 0.003514709, 0.03701494, -0.0047574765, 0.0067672534, 0.08913908, 0.0014652971, 0.009258712, -0.03202012, -0.024361957, -0.10464151, -0.033407286, -0.0027610548, -0.00944446, -0.0024300436, -0.0232218, 0.0094572455, 0.018079767, 0.23599343, -0.0063236416, 0.034273528, 5.9618044E-4, 0.010737699, 0.008162582, 0.0025107688, 0.007046912, 0.0026148462, -6.691977E-4, 0.0018003252, -0.017509019, 0.0071865367, 0.17709938, -0.0027926106, 0.0041772844, 0.24446069, 0.0035891477, 0.090311974, -0.005678741, 0.002527207, -0.043642007, 0.013362809, -0.10237697, 0.004665849, 0.029806657, 8.510543E-4, 0.008034529, 0.0037261287, 0.0016963077, -0.0065462743, 0.0014083247, -0.09163139, -7.1395264E-4, 0.0034422423, 2.2180262E-4, -0.050950024, 0.052165035, -6.5167714E-4, 0.09660987, 0.059556033, 0.0011484445, 0.0048205433, 0.016215535, -0.0074894307, -4.8624526E-4, 0.09030299, -0.031675506, 0.035420638, 0.00863125, 0.0062305178, -2.9943243E-4, 0.017759249, -0.007217323, -0.17156895, -0.08075601, 0.013375583, -0.0057125236, 0.0019819727, 0.0045942706, -9.6630485E-4, -0.0056799883, -0.001163379, 0.026658272, 0.0045382543, 0.0053815856, -0.0019246427, -0.0020221453, -0.0036204413, -0.016369255, -0.07884872, 0.0012176841, -0.0077565406, 0.08828778, -0.18202521, 0.0031140386, -0.013568612, 0.03727499, 0.0029328368, -0.009444142, 0.061891776, -0.0021317177, 7.041842E-5, -0.06919885, -0.022822084, -0.009733031, 0.0038881213, 0.2372824, 0.15371381, -0.0267819, -0.048720658, 0.029161548, -0.16049597, 0.023316571, 0.0020684062]]

This is the type converter i used

```
@TypeConverter
public static String fromRecognition(SimilarityClassifier.Recognition recognition) {
    if (recognition == null) {
        return (null);
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<SimilarityClassifier.Recognition>() {
    }.getType();
    String json = gson.toJson(recognition, type);
    return json;
}

@TypeConverter
public static SimilarityClassifier.Recognition toRecognition(String recognitionString) {
    if (recognitionString == null) {
        return (null);
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<SimilarityClassifier.Recognition>() {
    }.getType();
    SimilarityClassifier.Recognition recognition = gson.fromJson(recognitionString, type);
    return recognition;
}
```

column in data base is given as

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "record")
@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
private SimilarityClassifier.Recognition record;




public SimilarityClassifier.Recognition getRecord() {
    return record;
}

public void setRecord(SimilarityClassifier.Recognition record) {
    this.record = record;
}
```

similarityclassifier.Recognition is given below

public class Recognition {

```
private final String id;
private final String title;
private final Float distance;
private Object extra;

private RectF location;
private Integer color;
private Bitmap crop;

public Recognition(
        final String id, final String title, final Float distance, final RectF location) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.distance = distance;
    this.location = location;
    this.color = null;
    this.extra = null;
    this.crop = null;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public Float getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public RectF getLocation() {
    return new RectF(location);
}

public Bitmap getCrop() {
    return this.crop;
}

public Integer getColor() {
    return this.color;
}

public Object getExtra() {
    return this.extra;
}


public void setExtra(Object extra) {
    this.extra = extra;
}

public void setColor(Integer color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public void setLocation(RectF location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public void setCrop(Bitmap crop) {
    this.crop = crop;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    String resultString = "";
    if (id != null) {
        resultString += "[" + id + "] ";
    }

    if (title != null) {
        resultString += title + " ";
    }

    if (distance != null) {
        resultString += String.format("(%.1f%%) ", distance * 100.0f);
    }

    if (location != null) {
        resultString += location + " ";
    }

    return resultString.trim();
}
```

}
If anyone else encountered this issue, please help

Comment: Can you share the structure of `SimilarityClassifier.Recognition`

Comment: @vizsatiz i have updated it in above